# Именительный или творительный падеж с глаголом «называют»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, падежи, глаголы, управление

*Синдром усталости глаз называют **астенопия/астенопией.***
Подскажите, как правильно?
А может быть, синдром усталости глаз называют "астенопия"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В толковом словаре:
[назва́ть](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C), ***св.*** кого-что (**кем-чем** или ***кто-что***).
**1.** Дать название, имя и т. п. кому-либо, чему-либо.
*Назвать сына Андреем, а дочь Ольгой. Щенка назвали Шарик. Назвать яхту "Звезда".*

В словаре управления:
[назва́ть](http://rus-yaz.niv.ru/doc/punctuation-rosental/fc/slovar-205-1.htm#zag-929)
I. (дать имя, название и т. п.) сочетается с имен. и твор. падежами [**кто-что / кем-чем**].
*Новорожденная дочь Анны, названная тоже Анной, заболела* (Л. Толстой). [Т. п.]
*Мордочка [у теленка] беленькая, назвать бы Беляночка, или Снежная* (Панова). [И. п.]

1. Оба варианта грамотны (стоит, правда, отметить, что творительный падеж используется много чаще), кавычки не нужны.

*Необходимость постоянно читать или рассматривать изображение на близком расстоянии способствует развитию утомления глазодвигательных мышц, которое врачи-офтальмологи **называют** аккомодативная **астенопия.***

*Cиндром хронической или периодической усталости глаз медики **называют астенопией.***

2. *В медицине усталость глаз **называют термином «астенопия».***
   Такой вариант (Т. п. + И. п. в кавычках) используется при наличии [родового слова](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/75-kav2) (термин).

P. S. Из вопроса: *"Синдром усталости глаз называют **"астенопия"".***
Кавычки одинаковой конфигурации рядом (подряд) не используются. Наружные — обычно «елочки» (Alt 0171 и 0187), внутренние — "лапки". [«слово "кавычки"»]